# How many threads should one use in a general class or function, used by different users on different architectures?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

EDIT: Assume that the number of elements in the vectors, although equal, is arbitrary. This means that the vector might contain only a few elements (e.g. 10!), in which cases using threads would make no sense.

Suppose we want to implement a concurrent version of `operator+=` for a general purpose class that different people are going to use, on different architectures.
The `operator+=` simply sums all the elements of two `std::vector`s.
Let's imagine we have a lots of elements in said vectors, enough to use parallelism, and that both `std::vector`s have equal size.

We also assume that we use threads, similarly as described in the first chapter of "C++ Concurrency in Action". Something like this:

```cpp
 Foo& asynchronous_sum(const Foo& rhs) {
        unsigned long const length=vec.size();
        unsigned long const min_per_thread=25;
        unsigned long const max_threads=(length+min_per_thread-1)/min_per_thread; 
        unsigned long const hardware_threads= std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        unsigned long const num_threads=std::min(hardware_threads!=0?hardware_threads:2,max_threads);
        unsigned long const block_size=length/num_threads; 
        std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_threads-1); 
        int block_start = 0;
        for(unsigned long i=0;i<(num_threads-1);++i) {
            int block_end=block_start;
            block_end += block_size;
            threads[i]=std::thread([&](int start, int end) {
                 for (int i = start; i < end; ++i) {
                    vec[i] += rhs.vec[i];
                 }}, block_start,block_end);
            block_start=block_end; 
        }
        for (int i = block_start; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
            vec[i] += rhs.vec[i];
        }
        for (auto& current_thread: threads) {
            current_thread.join();
        }
 
        return *this;
    }
```

Note that `25` is an arbitrary number chosen by the book's author.

Let's now assume that we want to create `N` threads, where `N` is the optimal number of threads on a given architeture. So user `A` might have `N=5`, and user `B` might get `N=3`, depending on their architecture.

Is there any way to achieve this for a *general purpose* class?
...this could also be read as, how do "parallel algorithms" in C++ achieve this?

Comment: The answer likely lies somewhere around [std::thread::hardware_concurrency](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's probably true, and we already use it. However, there might be some circumstances in which threads might be too much (e.g. too small `std::vector`s). Also, the arbitrary number here (`25`) might not be suitable for all sizes (I'm guessing).

Comment: just make it configurable by the caller

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's what I initially thought. But then why doesn't the standard library do that with parallel algorithms? How would they achieve the "best" results?

Comment: At some point you hit the memory-bus bandwidth limit (this can be as low as 2 or 3 threads).  So the only possible answer is to test in your production environment with realistic data sets.

Comment: the standard library provides a simplified interface with no specification of how the parallelism is implemented, it probably doesn't perform optimally in all possible situations

Comment: You can't just throw threads at things. Sometimes you have multiple instances of a class, each running using their own thread or you can have one class running multiple threads. Having them both at the same time will only slow things down. So *shock* threads also need design (to avoid competing for the same resources, keep them from overusing your cache etc. and you datastructures must match, your datasets must be large enough). That's even before synchronization between threads is considered : do you need mutex, atomics, reader/writer locks?

Comment: So summary, NO a general answer is not available.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Then why does standard, parallel algorithms don't let the user choose the number of threads and stuff? How they decide that?

Comment: @Bluesky many standard algorithms don't have a goal of being optimal for every workload and every architecture; rather they prefer to keep their algorithms simple and general and try to be "good enough" for most architectures and workloads.  If eking out every last ounce of efficiency is necessary, you'll probably need to use custom code rather than standard algorithms.  (But in most cases, maximum efficiency is *not* necessary, rather the code only needs to be fast enough that nobody complains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters that must be tuned for optimal performance on parallel hardware are numerous: beyond a simple count of execution agents, CPU affinities, minimum block sizes, GPU thread layouts, and prefetch strategies all depend on the application and the machine.  Standardizing a **unified** representation of these disparate variables would be inordinately complicated and quickly outdated.

As such, rather than attempting to provide detailed access to the platform, the standard library parallel algorithms instead target programs that do not handle parallelism in other ways themselves.  Accordingly, the library may assume that it is the only user of parallelism on the hardware.  Common implementations then use a process-wide **thread pool** to execute parallel algorithms, with heuristics for block sizes.  This supports nested parallel algorithm calls in a reasonably natural way, since the thread counts do not explode.

It might therefore be worth using the standard parallel algorithms in your mathematical functions, in hopes that a client could benefit from them alone or in concert with their own usage thereof.  It remains a risk, however, that the client needs more sophisticated parallelism and your efforts merely complicate matters.  Doing more than using `<execution>` practically guarantees such an outcome.